# Creating clickable video thumbnails that load video on the same page above

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube, embed

I'm trying to make a video gallery of all my youtube videos for my website. So far I have created a grid of thumbnails of the video, and above it I have an iframe of my most recent video. I want to make it so that when the user clicks on one of the thumbnails below the main video, that the most recent video iframe will be replaced by that video. I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Example of what I'm trying to make:

http://tubepress.com/demo/

here is my code so far:

```
<section class="second clearfix">
<header>
    <h1>Video Academy</h1>
</header>


<h2>Most recent video here</h2>
<p>Description of video</p>

<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 mbl">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ZuGHts631vM" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<article class="video">
    <figure>
        <a class ="thumbnails" data-video="www.youtube.com/embed/zH3ZohGnjcg"><img class="videoThumb" src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/zH3ZohGnjcg/mqdefault.jpg"></a>
    </figure>
    <h3 class="videoTitle">video1</h3>
    <p class ="time">6:13</p>

</article>

<article class="video">
    <figure>
        <a class="thumbnails" data-video="www.youtube.com/embed/_ZSefvtdYiY"><img class="videoThumb" src="https://secure-b.vimeocdn.com/ts/178/010/178010767_295.jpg"></a>
    </figure>
    <h3 class="videoTitle">video 2</h3>
    <p class ="time">4:36</p>

</article>

<article class="video">
    <figure>
        <a class="thumbnails" data-video="www.youtube.com/embed/_ZSefvtdYiY"><img class="videoThumb" src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/_ZSefvtdYiY/mqdefault.jpg"></a>
    </figure>
    <h3 class="videoTitle">video 3</h3>
    <p class ="time">15:23</p>

</article>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hoveritem").click(function() {
        var change = $(this).find('.videoThumb').data('video');

        $(".embed-responsive-item").attr('src', change);

    });
});
```

I tried using javascript, but right now as my code is now clicking a thumbnail does nothing. I feel like I'm close, can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: I would recommend looking at the youtube API reference - https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference I'm using this and it's great! It will make life much easier if you want to have more control over the youtube embedded videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this without javascript. Name your iframe using

```
name="iframe-name"
```

so,

```
<iframe name="iframe-name" class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ZuGHts631vM" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

then target the link, to your iframe with

```
target="iframe-name"
```

so,

```
<article class="video">
    <figure>
        <a target="iframe-name" class ="thumbnails" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/zH3ZohGnjcg"><img class="videoThumb" src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/zH3ZohGnjcg/mqdefault.jpg"></a>
    </figure>
    <h3 class="videoTitle">video1</h3>
    <p class ="time">6:13</p>

</article>

<article class="video">
    <figure>
        <a target="iframe-name" class="thumbnails" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/_ZSefvtdYiY"><img class="videoThumb" src="https://secure-b.vimeocdn.com/ts/178/010/178010767_295.jpg"></a>
    </figure>
    <h3 class="videoTitle">video 2</h3>
    <p class ="time">4:36</p>

</article>

<article class="video">
    <figure>
        <a target="iframe-name" class="thumbnails" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/_ZSefvtdYiY"><img class="videoThumb" src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/_ZSefvtdYiY/mqdefault.jpg"></a>
    </figure>
    <h3 class="videoTitle">video 3</h3>
    <p class ="time">15:23</p>

</article>
```

Comment: No problem, all the best with your site.

Comment: I dont suppose you would know if its possible to do a similar thing with <h2> tags? Like I put the description of the video above it in an <h2> or maybe a <p> tag and when clicking the thumbnail can I replace that respective tag as well?

Comment: If you embed the video and the description in a separate webpage eg."www.mysite.com/video1-and-description.html" you can then change part of the <a> tag to HREF="www.mysite.com/video1-and-description.html" Does this answer your question?

Comment: Not sure if I follow. I'm trying to make it so when a thumbnail of the next video is clicked, then the header which is the video description also changes. I might have to use javascript for that i think

Comment: nevermind I figured it out! Used onclick javascript :)